# creat groups of numbers and add elements to it

Tags: matlab, grouping

I have a vector of numbers that is created from a loop and numbers relate to battery level like this:

```
for action= 1: max number of actions
 if a
 battery lvl= x;
 else
 battery lvl=y;
 end
end
```

the vector looks like this: [2 0.9 4 17 0.1 0 0 52 ....]

Max battery level Is 100. I need to create groups like 0-10, 10-20, 90-100
and then inside the "action" loop when the battery level is generated add it to one of the groups.
the outcome would look like this:

```
group1=[0 0 0 0 0.1 0.9...]
group2=[2 4 ...]
...
group10=[99 100 100 ...]
```

does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do here is not loop at all, you are binning by battery level with well defined bin "edges" 0-10, 10-20, ..., so you're better off treating this like a histogram

So taking some example input

```
v = [2 0 0 0 99 0 0.1 4 17 0.9 0 0 52 100 100];
```

You can define the bin edges and get the index of which bin each element of `v` falls into

```
edges = 0:10:100;
[~,~,idx] = histcounts( v, edges );
```

Then it's bad practise to use dynamically variable names like `group1,group2,group3,...`, and typically much easier and neater to use a cell array or structure to hold your groupings. This lets you loop more easily too, because you can have a cell called `groups` and index into `groups{1},groups{2},...` instead.

```
N = numel(edges)-1;
groups = cell(N,1);
for ii = 1:N
    groups{ii} = v( idx == ii );
end
```

Then you get

```
>> groups{1}
ans =
    2  0  0  0  0  0.1  4  0.9  0  0

>> groups{10}
ans =
    99   100   100
```

Comment: But I don't have the vector "v" at first. it's just being created during the loop. I want the partitions to be ready then put the generated numbers in them one by one.

Comment: You said in the post "my vector looks like this..." and "I need to create groups...", without a [mcve] which explicitly shows a contained, complete case for input data and expected output data I don't know how else to interpret your problem. I don't know what "I want the partitions to be ready" means, how can you partition something without having the _something_ first?